# How to use ng-repeat when we need to display two array one is normal string another is image

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I have two array which is given below

```
$scope.base64Array=[null, null, "/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD/2wBDAAgGBgcGBQgHBwcJCQ…cmnAgj0PvTTgZJ5osK4w8dahc1MTnOMcnionwR2JNKwXP/9k=", null, null, null];
$scope.products=["Wheat", "LCD Monitor", "Ethernet Cable", "Optical Mouse", "Rice", "Mac Mini RAM 4 GB"];
```

Here I have an null value in base64array if it is null then no need to display image and if i have base64 string i need to display in that image row

and my ionic view looks like

```
<ul class="list">

    <li class="item" ng-repeat="i in products" ui-sref="leadProduct" >
        {{i}}
        <br>
        <img ng-show="imgURI === undefined" ng-src="http://placehold.it/100x100">

    </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a `track by $index` to the repeat so you can tell which index you are at then index into base64Array.

```
<ul class="list">

    <li class="item" ng-repeat="i in products track by $index" ui-sref="leadProduct" >
        {{i}}
        <br>
        <img ng-show="base64Array[$index] != undefined" ng-src="{{'data:image/png;base64,'+base64Array[$index]}}">
        <img ng-show="base64Array[$index] == undefined" src="http://placehold.it/100x100">
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: ng-repeat="i in products track by $index" in here you did not mentioned the base64array how can it track

Comment: actually if there is null value then it should show the placeholdit size if it has base64 string then it should show the image like that

Comment: It's tracking the products index and uses this index on the base64 array. And I put back the placehold.it image.

Comment: i am getting this error GET http://localhost:8100/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD/2wBDAAgGBgcGBQgHBwcJCQgKDB…rUTk+negnIyDTSSRSAaRz7UEEcmnAgj0PvTTgZJ5osK4w8dahc1MTnOMcnionwR2JNKwXP/9k= 404 (Not Found)

Comment: I updated the nc-src to be `{{'data:image/png;base64,'+base64Array[$index]}}`
also here is a codepen for you to see http://codepen.io/Anthonyzou/pen/mVrxoy

Comment: i have one question in the base64Array=[]; contains the base64 string from server by $http.get. so, if the array contains more then one base 64 string then will it automatically display the image in respect to that position

Comment: Yes it should be in the same order as given by the server.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/99003/discussion-between-mohan-gopi-and-denixtry).

Comment: actually
i need to invoke camera function and
i have to post it to server
what is 'data:image/png;base64,'+base64Array[$index] does if you tell me i can get a clear understanding
and also the size of the image is no 100x100 it shows the size which is teken from the server

Answer (score 0):

Try process this two arrays before assignment, loop the base64Array, remove the null item and the same index item in products.

```
var tmp_base64Array = ["/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD..."];
var tmp_products = ["Ethernet Cable"];
```

After process the two arrays would be like this, then assignment to $scope.

edit:

```
$scope.products = [
  { "name": "Wheat", "imgUrl": null }, 
  { "name": "LCD Monitor", "imgUrl": "/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABA..." }
];

<ul class="list"> 
  <li class="item" ng-repeat="product in products" ui-sref="leadProduct" >    
    {{product.name}}
    <img ng-src="{{product.imgUrl || 'http://placehold.it/100x100'}}"> 
  </li> 
</ul>
```

Comment: actually my output should provide all the six names and placeholdit image if null value if base64 exist then disply the image

Comment: sorry i dont understand you

Comment: `$scope.products = [
   {
    "name": "Wheat",
    "imgUrl": null
   },
   {
    "name": "LCD Monitor",
    "imgUrl": "/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABA..."
   }
  ];`  `<ul class="list">
    <li class="item" ng-repeat="product in products" ui-sref="leadProduct" >
        {{product.name}}
        <br>
        <img ng-src="{{product.imgUrl || 'http://placehold.it/100x100'}}">
    </li>
  </ul>`  sorry, my mistaken, try change the data form like this.

Comment: ok, at first i misunderstood the question, sorry for the confuse.

Comment: is it possible like $scope.views =[ { "name": $scope.products, "imgUrl": $scope.base64Array }]; like this because i am getting the products and base64 string from server

Comment: i think it may not work. but you can transfer the data form after receive the server response.